# G+: how to get plusone feed via api call?

Tags: google-plus, google-plus-one

i've googled all over, read through the APIs.

The best I can find is this [snippet](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/json-rpc/0qjVx8RbWhI/xfBwWFHRcNgJ), and I have no idea how he figured out this much.

anybody?

Answer (score 0):

[This guy](http://randomistas.tekeu.com/2011/07/04/reverse-engineering-the-google-1-button-using-firebug/) appears to have reverse engineered it with fiddler, maybe this is a private api and everyone is reversing it.